# How to get global pose of a specific model's link in a gazebo world?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I get exact pose of a specific link of a model in Gazebo simulated world? To get model's (i.e. base_link) global position I call `rosservice call gazebo/get_model_state '{model_name: my_model_name}` but what I really need is a global pose of my lidar's link.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237895/how-to-get-global-pose-of-a-specific-model%27s-link-in-a-gazebo-world?/) by [Constantine](https://answers.ros.org/users/27063/constantine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can get a list of gazebo links and their states from `/gazebo/link_states` topic.

Here is a [python script](https://github.com/bgromov/thymio_gazebo/blob/master/thymio_description/scripts/gazebo_link_pose) that republishes poses in `geometry_msgs/Pose` format. You can find the names of links either in Gazebo GUI or on `/gazebo/link_states` topic itself.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2016-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4